# Por que o código imprime 0 ao invés de 5?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Por que este código imprime `0` ao invés de `5`?

```
class B {
    private int b;
    public int getB() { return b; }
    public void setB(int b) { b=b; }
}

class A {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setB(5);
        System.out.println(b.getB());
    }
}
```

Execute-o via [Ideone](https://ideone.com/z6k3U1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Porque o código está atribuindo o parâmetro `b` para o próprio parâmetro `b` e o atributo `b` da classe não está sendo alterado. Quando há ambiguidade, vence o símbolo local. Se o parâmetro tivesse outro nome, funcionaria. Mas como não é legal mudar um nome só para contornar isso, afinal isto poderia afetar a legibilidade, deve explicitar que deseja mexer na variável da classe, indicando com `this.b`. Assim:

```
class B {
    private int b;
    public int getB() { return b; }
    public void setB(int b) { this.b = b; }
}

class A {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setB(5);
        System.out.println(b.getB());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lTffPu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hmccrvzp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/ThisDesambiguation.java).

Comment: Achei que o símbolo local considerado seria o da referência, mas então no caso há um mais específico: o próprio parâmetro!

Answer (score 4):

Você deve utilizar `this.b` para referenciar o atributo da sua classe. 
Dessa forma, seu código da classe B deve ser:

```
class B {
  private int b;
    public int getB() { return this.b; }
    public void setB(int b) { this.b=b; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O código `b=b;` não tem efeito algum no método `public void setB(int b)` da classe B.
Quando o existe um parâmetro com o mesmo nome do campo (field) é necessário usar o `this` para acessar o campo e o motivo de estar imprimindo `0` é porque este é o valor inicial atribuído a variáveis e campos do tipo `int`.

Comment: Quando possuir reputação suficiente, poderá enviar comentários tanto na pergunta quanto nas respostas de outros usuários, mas até lá, atente-se em dar apenas respostas que acrescentem algo a discussão. No momento, sua resposta acrescenta em nada em relação às respostas anteriores.